# css: does every class support :hover state?

Tags: html, css

If I use a class for a normal div, can I write the css like:

```
.messagebc:hover {
...
}
```

Is it legal?

Comment: It's important to note that very few large sites still support IE 6.  I wouldn't go out of your way to ensure you get mirrored functionality with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's ineffiecient to use :hover on non-link elements.

Avoid the :hover pseudo-selector for non-link elements for IE clients.

> If you use :hover on non-anchor
>   elements, test the page in IE7 and IE8
>   to be sure your page is usable.   If
>   you find that :hover is causing
>   performance issues, consider
>   conditionally using a JavaScript
>   onmouseover event handler for IE
>   clients.

:hover pseudo-selector to non-link elements is a very ineffiecient selector (e.g):
    For example:

```
h3:hover {...}
.foo:hover {...}
#foo:hover {...}
div.faa :hover {...}
```

The :hover pseudo-selector on non-anchor elements is known to make IE7 and IE8 slow in some cases*.  When a strict doctype is not used, IE7 and IE8 will ignore :hover on any element other than anchors. When a strict doctype is used, :hover on non-anchors may cause performance degradation.

[More info on un-effiecient selectors](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors)

Answer (score 4):

why havn't you simply tried it? yes, you can (in all modern browsers, the IE6 knows :hover only on `a`, if i remember right).

Comment: You remember right. So the question is more: does all elements support :hover ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use `:hover` for all elements in modern browsers (IE7+).
While IE6 support `:hover` only for `<a>` elements, you should write you html and css so, that you won't need to use js-patches (for example, in list-menus just use `<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>`, not `<a><li><a>` and assign `:hover` to the link element. This should do the trick.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, however in IE6 you can set `:hover` only on ANCHOR elements.

Answer (score 3):

Only ie6 does not support it on elements other than `<a>`, but that can be fixed with a simple javascript: [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Answer (score 3):

The share of the ie6 is 5.55% and is
decreasing everyday 
So You may use it 
[Wikipedia ie6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ie6)

Answer (score 2):

Every current browser will support it. If you need it to work in an older browser such as IE6 then take a look at @Willem's link.

Answer (score 0):

If by the term class you mean HTML element then yes per W3C spec you can use the :hover selector on all elements. Whether you should or not is a different question.

**Sources:**

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp
http://www.w3.org/2009/cheatsheet/#search,%3Ahover