# Change class of active bootstrap button on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I want to change the class of this bootstrap button on hover with jQuery, so that the styling of the button changes to the new custom class, that I would like to add with "addClass":

```
<div id="tile-sort" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="sort-hello" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
        <input type="radio" name="sort-option" value="hello">Hello
    </label>
</div>
```

The below code works:

```
$('#tile-sort').hover(
    function() {
        $('.btn-primary').addClass('sort-hover-nonactive');
    },
    function() {
        $('.btn-primary').removeClass('sort-hover-nonactive');
    }
);
```

However, if I attempt to change the class of this "active" bootstrap button on hover with jQuery:

```
<div id="tile-sort" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="sort-goodbye" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active">
        <input type="radio" name="sort-option" value="goodbye">Goodbye
    </label>
</div>
```

The below code ***does not*** work:

```
$('#tile-sort').hover(
    function() {
        $('.btn-primary.active').addClass('sort-hover-active');
    },
    function() {
        $('.btn-primary.active').removeClass('sort-hover-active');
    }
);
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction for this class adding/removing to happen?

Comment: what is it that's not working with it? could you pls elaborate on that?

Comment: ...because it appears to be working perfectly for me: http://www.bootply.com/46QrDSeAc2

Comment: Yes... the class 'sort-hover-active' is not being added (with "addClass") to"<label id="sort-goodbye" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active">".

Comment: it is, look, I'm demonstrating it for you, added a background color to the class: http://www.bootply.com/kTz8GBQ7Ct

Comment: In your bootply... can you make it so that the blue background of the button changes to red on hover?

Comment: Great... just saw that. I'll look elsewhere in my code for a conflict. Thank you!

Comment: The answer is that it needs "!important" to be added. Without it, it does not change the color. If you want to respond as an answer... I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: ...moreover, if you edit your post adding something like "the problem was that the css styling I applied to it didn't appear to have an effect on the element", then I'll be happy to vote your question up, removing that -1 (as it stands right now)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue might be coming from somewhere else, maybe you didn't set `!important` on your custom css?

I've tried it as follows:

```
.sort-hover-active {
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://www.bootply.com/kTz8GBQ7Ct)

#### EDITED:

Following the comments of @jshthornton, I edited the code to be more in line with bootstrap's native code. Here is what I did:

```
$('#tile-sort').hover(
    function() {
        $('#sort-goodbye').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger');
    },
    function() {
        $('#sort-goodbye').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary');
    }
);
```

This way you're basically making use of existing bootstrap code instead of applying cumbersome workarounds like `!important` which should preferably be avoided, if possible.

And **[here is a demo of that](http://www.bootply.com/cqpNw1GOqC)**

Comment: Do not encourage people who are still learning to use bad practises such as !important

Comment: using bootstrap you're often put up with it's limitations too, however awesome it is, it just doesn't cover every possible scenario, so sometimes you will have to workaround it, i believe this is a scenario like that...

Comment: I highly disagree. Unless you're dealing with print stylesheets which need to forcibly be changed then !important should be outright banned. Especial if you're teaching someone who may not understand the consequences of using it.

Comment: @jshthornton dude, show us your wisdom and provide a better answer, i'll bow in front of it if it brings results, which is the ultimate goal... I do use `!important` sometimes, am i a bad coder? maybe, but i at least deliver, not just criticize...

Comment: I have no problem with you supplying an answer - it works. But you should at least inform OP as to the caveats of your solution; otherwise it is just careless.

Comment: ok, i admit you have a point, so i updated my answer, think that should do it ;)

Comment: Thank you both for this answer and explanation of `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

With js:

```
.btn-primary.active.sort-hover-active {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Using it like this may be overwritten time to time. If this is the case just find the selector path which has the strongest weight.
http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Without js:

```
.btn-primary.active:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

This is the "best" way to do it if you only need visual changes on hover. This is also the least intensive to the DOM due to less mutations. With this method you can remove your JS hover code.
This also has issues in some legacy IEs. Read more here: [css: does every class support :hover state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204527/css-does-every-class-support-hover-state)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `toggleClass` method and `hover` event, check this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#my-btn").hover(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("btn-danger");
  });

});
```

```html
<!-- libs -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- button -->
<a class='btn btn-primary' id='my-btn'>
   class change on hover
</a>
```

If you want to change the text or reuse this logic
, you can create a plugin check this example(`toggleBtn plugin`):

```js
// pluglin toogleBtn
jQuery.fn.extend({
    toggleBtn: function (normalBtnOps, hoverBtnOps) {
        var self = this;
        self.attr('class', 'btn ' + normalBtnOps.class);
        self.text(normalBtnOps.text);
        this.hover(function () {
           self
           .attr('class', 'btn ' + hoverBtnOps.class)
           .text(hoverBtnOps.text);
        }, function(){
            self
           .attr('class', 'btn ' + normalBtnOps.class)
           .text(normalBtnOps.text);
        });
    }
});



// test Plugin
$('#my-btn').toggleBtn(
  {'class': 'btn-primary','text' : 'normal btn'},
  {'class': 'btn-danger','text' : 'hover btn'}
 );
 
 $('#my-btn-2').toggleBtn(
  {'class': 'btn-warning','text' : 'warning!'},
  {'class': 'btn-dark','text' : 'Dark!'}
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<a id='my-btn' href='#'></a>
<a id='my-btn-2' href='#'></a>
```

Good Luck!.