# Hover Doesn't Work On Unfilled Areas of SVG Path

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I have a portfilio (https://portfolio.umairstem.now.sh/) home page where there are svg icons. When the mouse hovers over the icon, I want it to turn light blue. The problem is that when the mouse goes over the gaps in the SVG, the effect does not occur. The image below shows what I mean if I am not being clear. I have tried to add a `background` or `padding` but that displaces the elements on the page.

My CSS is Below:

```
svg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 5vw;
    min-height: 2rem;
    max-height: 4rem;
    scale: 0.5;
}

.Fill-1:hover{//Fill-1 is the SVG class name
   fill: #1793D1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `fill` of the path when hovering over the containing element, which in this case can be the `<svg/>`:

```
svg:hover path {
  fill: blue
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq78zxwm/)

Comment: This is effectively the same answer I provided, except it affects all SVGs on the page, even ones that aren't links, creating a confusing UI. Further, it's [inefficient to use `:hover` on non-link elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4204600/203130).

Comment: @coreyward In your answer you changed the fill of the svg instead of the path. And it's inefficient to use `:hover` on non-link elements *in IE7/8*, which is a browser that almost no one uses today.

Comment: `fill` cascades.

Comment: @coreyward you're right, I didn't know that... I was under the impression that your answer didn't work because of the OP's comment

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `hover` pseudo-selector on the SVG element, use it on a containing element instead. For example:

```
a:hover svg {
  fill: #1793d1;
}
```

Note: you'll need to remove the other selectors and styles for this to work as shown; if you really want to be overly specific about the selector you can, but I don't recommend it. `a:hover .Fill-1` is excessive.

Comment: Is your `svg` in an `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `class="Fill-1"` from the path. Next you apply the styles - as everyone mentioned - to the svg element.

```css
body{background:black;}
svg{fill:white;}
svg:hover{fill:skyBlue;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256.000000 256.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g transform="translate(0.000000,256.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"><path d="M135 2552c-40-14-81-45-105-80l-25-36 0-1156 0-1156 24-35c13-19 40-46 60-60l36-24 1155 0 1155 0 36 24c20 14 47 41 60 60l24 35 0 1156 0 1156-24 35c-13 19-40 46-60 60l-36 24-1140 2c-627 0-1149-2-1160-5zm550-446c58-27 78-47 100-99 53-128-35-261-182-274-94-9-175 33-214 109-24 46-25 128-2 175 47 99 187 141 298 89zm1148-521c128-27 217-95 276-214 52-103 61-188 61-592l0-359-195 0-194 0-3 368-3 367-25 44c-45 80-113 109-206 90-60-12-112-53-143-114-20-38-21-56-21-397l0-358-195 0-195 0 0 575 0 575 195 0 195 0 0-76 0-76 51 57c101 110 233 146 402 110zm-1053-590l0-575-195 0-195 0 0 575 0 575 195 0 195 0 0-575z"></path></g></svg>
```